# Is $f$ continuous at$(0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
f(x, y) = \cases{\dfrac{2(x^3+y^3)}{x^2 + y} & if $(x, y)\neq (0,0)$\\
0 & if $(x, y) = (0,0)$
}
$$
It looks continuous, but my friend said it isn't. I tried to show discontinuity by taking various paths, but was only met with failure.  I couldn't prove it is continuous either. Please help.

Comment: What's the value of $f$ at $(2, -4)$?

Comment: Is it meant to be $x^2 + y^2$ in the denominator?

Comment: @JohnGowers Oh I missed that the function is not even defined everywhere. What a blunder. Thanks.

Comment: @Adienl Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $x=t$ and $y=-t^2+t^3=-t^2(1-t)$ with $t\to 0$

$$\dfrac{2(x^3+y^3)}{x^2 + y}=2\cdot\dfrac{t^3-t^6(1-t)^3}{t^2-t^2+t^3}=2-t^3(1-t)\to 2$$

thus $f(x,y)$ in not continuos in $(0,0)$.

Comment: So it is true if I define f to be 0 at all points $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y=0$. Do you also mind telling me how did you think of this path?

Comment: Note that $f(x,y)$ is not defined for $y=-x^2$ with exception for$ y=x=0$ where we have $f(0,0)=0$ by definition. Here we are looking for the continuity in $(0,0)$, thus what you have to show is the existence or not exitence of the limit in $(0,0)$. Since the function is not defined for $y=-x^2$ you select a path such that $x^2+y$ cancel out with a remainder such that the limit is $\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it helps to do a [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2(x%5E3+%2B+y%5E3)%2F(x%5E2+%2B+y)+from+-1+to+1):

[image]

Can you do it from here?

Comment: This function is just wrong. Thanks for answering though.